# How to remove/ignore .htaccess file from gallery feed

Tags: php, file

I've mafe an infinite scrolling gallery and it works as intended, php code supplies the the feed with images with this code (below) from the directory. However there is a problem, I can't make this script to ignore htaccess file, so its 1 image which is always broken. How to disregard this file?

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 
    $dir = "img";
    $allowed = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg');
    $ext = pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    

        if(is_dir($dir)){
            if($dd = opendir($dir)){
                while (($f = readdir($dd)) !== false)
                  if($f != "." && $f != "..")
                      $files[] = $f;
                      $allowed = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg');
                      $ext = pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                      closedir($dd);
        } 
     
 
        $n = $_GET["n"];
        $response = "";
            for($i = $n; $i<$n+9; $i++){
                $response = $response.$files[$i%count($files)].';';
            }
            echo $response;
        }
     
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just add another check for `.htaccess` and use `in_array()` for better code clarity.

You can change

```
if($f != "." && $f != "..")
```

to

```
if(!in_array($f,[".","..",".htaccess"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, sir. I do understand ur logic, however I can't understand how should I write it inte code :(   i need to put it inside of while (($f = readdir($dd)) !== false)?

Comment: Yes, just replace your if condition as shown in the answer.